# USB cable not working

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode, macos

I'm using MacBook Air(MacOS Sierra) and have installed `Android File Transfer` on it.

The problem I'm getting occurs sometimes and works well the other time.

When I connect my phone with my PC with a USB cable, **no** option is shown on the phone screen about the **"Use USB for"** which should show 3 options:

1. Charging only
2. Transfer Files(MTP)
3. Transfer photos

Rather the phone starts getting charged without the above option occurring.

[image]

As mentioned above, this problem occurs sometimes but not every time.

[image]

I've also selected the **"USB Debugging feature** to tackle with the above problem but it doesn't seem to help.

What should I do?

Comment: I read this [somewhere](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67563/having-problem-in-usb-connection/68188#comment264765_68188) that using some kind of USB cable to not support media transfer. So, how do I distinguish between a real USB cable and the one with only power wire inside it?

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a different cable? USB cables tend to be cheaply made and any damage/normal use (pulling, stepping on, winds/unwinds) can create an intermittent connection. If you were able to copy a file between phone and PC, its a data cable, no way to tell otherwise.

Comment: @MorrisonChang With the same USB cable, I do face the problem sometimes and not every time. I haven't tried it with another USB cable.