# No charging or transfer despite USB debugging and working cable

Tags: adb, charging, 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-debugging

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 lite (SM-T110)

OS: Android 4.2.2

I want to connect the device with my computer. In the developer settings I activate USB Debugging - but nothing happens. There is also no option to select the USB behavior.
Even more: Unlike [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67563/having-problem-in-usb-connection) case, my device doesn't even charge. There's a red cross on the charging-battery icon.

What I tried so far:

- The cable works with other devices (charging and data), so it's not that.
- Factory resetting the device didn't help
- There's a setting to connect media with Kies. But I doubt that would let me us adb for management.
- In recovery mode, there's an option to install programs via adb. When selected, I'm told to install packages with sideload now. But neither adb nor heimdall manage to detect the device.
- My laptop runs gnu/linux, so I don't assume it to be a driver issue.

So now I'm turning to you ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ Thanks for any pointers*.

Comment: What happens if you shut down the tablet and connect it to a charger? Does the tablet boot into the "charger OS" (the full screen battery/charging progress display) or the regular Android?

Comment: Thanks for your answer =) it boots into the charger OS indeed (full screen battery)